# "I'm looking for a shop with clothes"

Tags: compound-nouns

Can we say

> I'm looking for a shop with clothes

For me it's not clear. It indicates that we are with these clothes, like with a friend?
Should be

> I'm looking for a clothes shop.

I've done some research, but nothing found.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dialect difference.

In the UK, The phrase "clothes shop" is natural and idiomatic.

In the USA, the phrase "clothing shop" is more common.

Fortunately, both are easy to understand by all English speakers.

These [ngrams graphs](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clothes%20shop%2Cclothing%20shop&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) show that both are common. But if you change to "American English" or "British English", you will see that "clothing shop" is more common in the USA.

You can also say "... a shop *that sells clothes*"  That is useful if you want to make it more complex "I'm looking for a shop that sells high-quality women's clothes in large sizes"

Comment: Thanks a lot. What about a sentence I'm looking for a shop with clothes?

Comment: That's not very idiomatic

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a clothing shop.

I hope you could explore the word "clothing" that was used in the sentence above.

As you see below, clothing represents collectively almost all the garments.

A clothes shop is okay too but personally I like a clothing shop for no reasons better than 'a clothes shop'.

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/clothing

Clothing is what your wear, like sweaters, shirts, pants, dresses, and so on. Your favorite piece of clothing might be your purple polka dotted tights.

Clothing is made of fabric and covers our bodies, keeps them warm or protects them from the sun, insects, sharp rocks and thorns, and other hazards. In some situations, clothing keeps people safe, as when medical workers wear scrubs, gloves, and masks to protect themselves and patients from infection. Often clothing reflects your personal values or religion, like a Muslim woman's hijab that covers her hair. The Old English root is claþ, "cloth or woven material."

Comment: We expect our answers to be detailed and explanatory. Please say a few more words and explain the sentence you are giving.